# Java Performance Bottleneck Profiling Tools

Tags: java, web-server, performance-analysis, profiling

I am looking for a performance profiling tool that can tell me the performance bottlenecks in my Java application and can give me a detailed overview of the most expensive method calls.

I have the following requirements:

1. I have a Java Enterprise Application, so the profiler should be able
   to measure the performance of the Java server application when some
   request arrives.
2. I am using JSF, Spring, and Spring Webflow. If some
   request arrives and as a result flow x is executed, the profiler
   should be able to list the performance of all methods called during
   the execution of flow x.
3. The profiler should be as lightweight as possible.
4. I am working on Linux with IntelliJ IDE and it would be great if the profiler has a IntelliJ integration for source code navigation
5. If possible, the profiler should be open source or at least there should be a free trial version.

Currently I am facing the problem that my server needs a lot of time for responding on certain requests and I want to know if there is any single method that is very slow or if the number of method calls is the problem.

Comment: The [microbenchmarks](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/230) in JDK9 would be useful for this.

Comment: @NonlinearFruit microbenchmarks seem to be worth trying. Currently I am working with a trial version of JProfiler. This profiler offers detailed statistics of method execution and it is easy to control.